# LaTeX3 variants with TF arguments

Tags: expansion, expl3, latex3

How to generate variants for functions with `T/F` arguments?

For example, I want make the first argument of `\tl_if_eq:nn(TF)` to be `V`. Should I write all the following:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnT  { VnT }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnF  { VnF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { VnTF }
```

or just simply

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nn { Vn }
```

By the way, if I only need to change the first argument, should I write the whole arg-spec list (i.e. `Vn` or `V` in the example)?

**Update (2017-12-21)**

Now there's a new function `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` in `l3candidate` for this:

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_eq:nn { V } { T, F, TF }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule, the second argument to `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` can only list the argument types up to the last that must get changed.

Thus

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnT  { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnT  { Vn }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnT  { VnT }
```

are all equivalent. Similarly, if one wanted to vary the second argument to, say, `x`, the equivalent declarations would be

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnT  { nx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnT  { nxT }
```

In the case of `(TF)` trailing arguments, all different function should be generated:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnT  { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnF  { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { V }
```

## Update

With the 2017-12-16 release of `expl3` code, one can simplify the above to

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_eq:nn { V } { T, F, TF }
```

More generally, this is also possible for

```
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \my_conditional_exp:nn { p, T, F, TF }

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \my__conditional_notexp:nn { T, F, TF }
```

(the `:Npnn` form can also be used, of course) so one can do

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \my_conditional_exp:nn { V } { p, T, F, TF }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \my_conditional_notexp:nn { V } { T, F, TF }
```

The third argument to `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` should only list suffixes that are present in the original definition of the conditional.

Comment: I guess we should look to make use of this new functionality across the core code ...